# How to connect MySQL database with JSF and Primefaces in Netbeans?

Tags: mysql, jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I'm building a Java Web project with JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 4 using Netbeans IDE 8.

I'm trying to connect a database that I made in MySQL with my netbeans project.

The problem is that when i create a new project and make an entity class from database and choose jdbc/sample and make JSF pages from those entity classes the program runs ok BUT when I choose a new connection (MySQL) and choose my database with my tables and make JSF pages from entity class, the project doesnt run.

The database is visible in netbeans it's also visible in phpmyadmin in wamp. I'm thinking it has to do something with glassfish resources.xml file that

I need to configure something there or maybe not.

**The short version of my problem:**

How to configure and how to connect my database made in mysql (not a sample one) with netbeans jsf primefaces project and create entity classes from database and make JSF pages from those entities ?

PS can anyone post some links - videos or tutorials regarding this problem also

Resolved1: The problem is with netbeans 8 in 7.4 and earlier versions it works...

RESOLVED2: In Netbeans 8 the problem is with JDBC Resources and Connection Pool... just follow this tutorial at the end of the page it will solve the problem https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html#troubleshooting

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to declare the new JDBC connection pool in `glassfish-resource.xml` and add the entity to the right Persistence Unit in `persistence.xml`

Next time, post the stack trace so it will help us identify your problem.

Comment: Ok thx how can i do that with persistence.xml and glassfish-resource.xml? I cant get to stack trace bcs my app wont deploy it says The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 seconds)
here is the full log http://justpaste.it/fkk0 plz help or I must go back to 7.4 :(

Comment: I succeeded to run it in 7.4 here is the stack trace error http://pastebin.com/LduGKDMy